# How could I find the earliest date a time as well as the most recent date and time in a data frame?

Tags: r, date, time, range

I have a column in my data frame of values formatted as `datet time`: `2017-09-11 08:00:00` and so forth.

I want to find the earliest date with the earliest time of that date as well as the last (most recent) date with the last time.

I am basically trying to find the range of this column to determine the difference in time.

Thanks!

Comment: `range(df$col)` will give you the first and last dates. `diff(range(df$col))` will give you the time difference. If the column is not already formatted as datetime class, run `df$col = as.POSIXct(df$col)` first.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I think you can use functions such min and max to do so.